# How to get information about code lines in Qt?

Tags: qt, mingw, line-numbers

I need to be able to read information about project lines in the Qt project which is building by MinGW.
How can I do it? Where I should include - /MAPINFO:LINES , to get output file with information about lines numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `__LINE__.`
Example:

```
qDebug()<<__LINE__<<"hi";
```